# How to add data from array to register when data is in byte?

Tags: assembly, emu8086

I need to put information from array x to ax, but my x is DB, byte, how to put it in correctly? Because putting it into al and then doing CBW doesn't work properly.
It works when x is word:

```
MOV ax, x[si]
```

I need to make it work when x is declared as byte in data segment, I'm trying to do:

```
MOV al, x[si]
CBW
```

But that doesn't work out, I get wrong answers of my function equations and it prints only a half of my x array.

```
data    SEGMENT 
a   DW  10000;   10000
b   DW -2
c   DB -3
x   DB 8,3, 1, -2; when DW, works fine
count = ($-x)/ 2
y   DB count dup(0AAh)
```

function where I use it:

```
out_loop:
    MOV al, x[si]  
    CBW
    PUSH ax
    MOV bx, offset isvb+2  
    PUSH bx
    CALL binasc
    MOV al, y[di]
    CBW     
    PUSH ax
    MOV bx, offset isvb+11 
    PUSH bx
    CALL binasc

    MOV dx, offset isvb
    MOV ah, 9h
    INT 21h 
;============================
    INC si     
    INC si
    INC di
    LOOP out_loop
out_end:
```

Comment: Please elaborate: what exactly do you mean `doesn't work out` - do you get an error, a crash, what?

Comment: Your error is probably elsewhere, sounds like you increment `si` by `2`. Please make sure you provide [mcve].

Comment: I get wrong answers of my function equations and it prints only a half of my x array, when I change x to DW, it prints all x I have declared and functions calculate properly

Comment: We'll need to see more of your code, then.

Comment: You have two `inc si` instructions per iteration.

Comment: @Michael Thank you for your notice, I just removed dividing by 2 in count, one ```inc si``` and it solved my problem correctly.